# Pandas read_sql_query fails with Presto Hive database

Tags: python, pandas, hive, presto

I've got an issue while trying to query a Presto database with a Hive connector and write the returned data to a CSV file. To date, I've successfully extracted data from this API many times; however, for my latest query, I'm hitting a memory ceiling due to the large number of records being returned.

Previously, I've been able to obtain a connection to the database, fetch all the data via a cursor, and then successfully write the data to a CSV file in one go using Pandas, as follows:

```
def df_from_presto_sql(connection, sql):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    return pd.DataFrame(
        data=data,
        columns=[x[0] for x in cursor.description]
    )
```

However, for my latest query, I've hit a memory limit, and the function above fails. To solve this, I've attempted to read data from the connection in chunks and append those chunks of data to the CSV file. In order to do so, I've used Pandas' read_sql_query method like so:

```
df_source = pd.read_sql_query(sql, connection, chunksize=chunksize)
```

This is unsuccessful, and throws an exception:

> 'NoneType' object is not iterable.

Note, that I get the same exception even if I omit the optional chunksize parameter.

Do you know why this isn't working? Or, do you have an example of Python code that is used to query a Presto Hive database and read data in chunks?